Code gets Stuck in Bull.Js process function and never terminated
code never reaches console.log("All job completed") and gets stuck in process function it is still waiting for job to processed even though there are no jobs present in queue how to resolve this
import Bull from 'bull';

const queue = new Bull('my-queue');

await queue.add({ data: 'Job 1' });

await queue.process(10,async(job,done)=>{
    try{
    console.log('Processing Job:', job.data);
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    done(null,job.data);
    }catch(err){
        done(err);
    }
})
console.log("All job completed ");


I want that if there are no jobs in queue then queue instance should be deleted and process function should be resolved
